# how to take text to next line when we press enter in material ui card

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

when i type the text in material ui textfield and hit enter ,typing goes to next line but when i click save that text
dont save into material ui card into next line it remains same in row form .
i am using material ui card where my text updated . and i am using material ui textfield to input the text .
i am using wordbreak all css property into card ,it take my manual text to next line but not that one which i type with textfield and press enter.
below is my code examples and output.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

for someone else who face this same problem.
i fixed this issue by simply giving this css property to my typography which was inside card .
whiteSpace: "break-spaces",